# Write to existing xml file without replacing it's contents (XmlWriter)

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio, xmlwriter

I encountered following issue,

I first write to my xml file like this:

```
 XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("course.xml", null);
 writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
 writer.WriteStartDocument();

 writer.WriteStartElement("Course");
 writer.WriteAttributeString("title", "Examle");
 writer.WriteAttributeString("started", "true");

 writer.WriteEndElement();
 writer.WriteEndDocument();
 writer.Close();
```

And xml output I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Course title="Example" started="true" />
```

After that I want to write more data to this xml file so I use my code again:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("course.xml", null);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
writer.WriteStartDocument();

writer.WriteStartElement("Course");
       writer.StartElement("Level");
              writer.StartElement("Module");
              writer.EndElement();
       writer.EndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Close();
```

And the xml output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Course>
    <Level>
        <Module>
        </Module>
    </Level>
</Course>
```

So it replaces my original data, and all attributes in the course tag. Therefore I need a way where it doesn't replace data, but instead add it inside existing tags.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML files are just sequential text files. They are not a database or a random-access file. There is no way to just write into the middle of them.

Comment: +1. Note that unlike CSV (or other line-based) formats one can't even append to XML file due to requirement to match closing tags. One can consider [document fragments](www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+xml+document+fragment) - XML without topmost node to allow append.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend parsing the entire xml document into memory, adding the new data, and then writing the whole document back out again.